# tensorflow object_detection train.py error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, tfrecord

I'm currently trying to retrain Google's [Tensorflow Object Detection](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)

I followed the steps in `sentdex's` [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U) (and probably like many of you did).

After I generated the `tf_records` and moved them in the directory `models/research/object_detection`, everything should be set for the training.

To initialize the training process I used: `python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config`

The result should be the command line printing the current step and accuracy reached, but instead i got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
    from object_detection import trainer
  File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import preprocessor_builder
  File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/research/object_detection/builders/preprocessor_builder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import preprocessor_pb2
  File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py", line 71, in <module>
    options=None, file=DESCRIPTOR),
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'
```

I am working on `Amazon's g2.2xlarge` with Ubuntu 16.04 which came with `tensorflow` and `nvidia cuda` drivers ready (i suppose).

Any ideas why the error? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You somehow have different versions of google protocol buffer library at play. The preprocessor_pb2.py was generated with a new (past 3.5) version of protobuf, which introduced the `file` argument to generated code (https://github.com/google/protobuf/blob/9f80df026933901883da1d556b38292e14836612/CHANGES.txt#L74). And whatever it is calling on line 71 in `/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/research/object_detection/protos/preprocessor_pb2.py` must have been compiled with an earlier version of `protoc`, that does not have this field.